# Equivalence tests for STP3 - location of maximum power

Tags: hypothesis-testing, mathematical-statistics, statistical-power, equivalence

Lehmann and Romano show in their Th 3.7.1 (Lehmann and Romano 2005, p81) when a UMP equivalence test $\phi_1$ exists and that it has a power that is maximised at some point $\theta^\star$ inside the equivalence region $[\theta_1, \theta_2]$.

Now suppose we have a second test $\phi_2$ that only differs in the upper point of the equivalence region $[\theta_1, \theta_3]$, with $\theta_3>\theta_2$. Then I think the power of the second test should be maximized at a point $\theta^\star_2$ that is larger than $\theta^\star$, and that this should follow from the stochastic ordering of the distribution family induced by the test statistic (assumed to be STP3 in Th 3.7.1).

Does anyone have any hints or suggestions on how to prove this?